# Developing/using modules for Loadrunner scripts

Tags: loadrunner

To get to the question, I would like to set the context and also explain the practice I follow.

### Using LR include directory

When I write custom c modules/functions for LR which will be used quite often, I put them all in a header `(*.h)` file and store it in LR installation directory where all the other LR modules live and are loaded when script is compiled `(C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LoadRunner\include)`. Then I can simply include it in scripts global header, example: `#include "genie.h"`. I know this is just one way and this method works but it requires us to place the header file in all the injector machines which is tedious task when you make some changes to the library your library. And if you create a directory, I am not sure how to tell LR to upload them to each injectors.

### Another method?

Create a directory along with with the scripts -

```
├───BP63_script
├───include
    ├───genie.h
    └───others.h
├───NI01_Script
└───NI02_Script
```

The problem is include directory isn't a script and controller will not upload it to the injectors/LGs. Is there a way to do it?
**Or if there is any other way of doing a modular scripting for LR?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no built in way to share resources such as files or actions between scripts but there are two possible solutions:

1) The "recommended" solution is a shared directory in the network. Make a directory that all LGs can access and put the files there.

2) If you are feeling adventurous, there is another, less tested way. Create the include directory as in the question and then create a symbolic link with mklink /D from that directory into each of the scripts. I tested this in our lab with a single action file and it worked but this is not something official we recommend (yet).

If you try #2 it could be nice if you post the result here or send it to the feedback email in VuGen (Help -> Send us your feedback) and mention my name (Boris).

Comment: #1 works particularly well since the header directory gets hit only at the beginning of the test when the users are 'compiled' for execution.  If you are using cloud generators this can be problematic as there is often not a shared file service between these load generators.